# Open concept kitchen

Tags: receptacle

For a 26ft outside load bearing wall i am opening up with 2 26ft lvl, Will I need a support column in the middle or can i just do the support columns on both ends. I  have enlarged my kitchen. Now I need to remove the existing outside load bearing wall for the open floor plan.

Comment: The cost of an engineer's review on this is dwarfed by the cost of the structure collapsing. I'm sure there is *some sort* or LVL that will bear the load... But what about shear resistance? What about lateral deflection? Your description puts this project firmly outside layman territory. You're not talking about a 5 foot window, here.

Answer (score 6):

Removing an outside load bearing wall is serious, it will be worth the few hundred dollars to ask the opinion of a structural engineer. They will be able to calculate the loads and give you a stamp of approval. I take it you're doing this without pulling any permits.